# Almost-Binomial Distribution (Different Success Chances per Trial)

Tags: binomial-distribution, monte-carlo, markov-process

Let's say I have received complaints that my coin is not random enough after some people got 10 heads. My coin *was* truly random, but I want it to feel random, not be random.

This is a pretty common problem actually. A lot of times people see patterns where no pattern exists.

The solution is to tweak the random aspect. (I don't know what the official term is: I think Quasi-Random. I've seen some people refer to this as Psuedo-Random). Basically you modify the odds (without the user knowing) so that streaks become less likely.

### The Actual Question

> After each heads, the chance to get heads drops by 10 points.
> After each tails, the chance to get tails drops by 10 points.

So if I get HHTHH, the odds of heads is (50% - 40% + 10% = 20%). Chance of getting 5 heads in a row goes from 1 in 32 to 3 in 2500 (1 / 2<sup>5</sup> to 5! / 10<sup>5</sup>).

What is (or even is there a) the mathematical way to find the number of heads after n trials?

---

I'm pretty sure I found the answer to a simplified version, with 25 instead of 10 (just by calculating the odds of each scenario), but I want a good method of solving it. With a 10 though, this problem seems to be exponentially longer to solve the way I tried. I'd like to know a method that would work with any weighting-factor.

Comment: What you describe is a kind of *dynamic random walk* which can be modeled as a markov chain.

Comment: Do you want the expected number of heads after $n$ trials, or the probability that you have $h$ heads after $n$ trials? The expected number of heads is $n/2$ by symmetry. Let $H$ be the number of heads, $T$ be the number of tails. Then $n = H + T$. So $\mathbb{E}(H) + \mathbb{E}(T) = n$, and also $\mathbb{E}(H) = \mathbb{E}(T)$ by the symmetry of the problem statement, so $\mathbb{E}(H) = n/2$.